# Why does 'socket.handshake.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || socket.handshake.address' result in 2 IP addresses?

Tags: socket.io, ip, x-forwarded-for

I'm using `socket.io` to get an IP address:

```
var clientIp = socket.handshake.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || socket.handshake.address
var arr = clientIp.split(":");
var ip = _.last(arr);
```

The ip variable is set with the value :"124.202.182.82,100.116.251.26"

Why where there two IP addresses in the last element of arr?

Answer (score 0):

You've used `:` as the delimiter instead of `,` when calling `split()`.

Addresses in `X-Forwarded-For` header are separated by comma.

[More information about X-Forwarded-For on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-For)